# Rails: Skip after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, callback, after-create

I have 2 models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :client
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

and I normally create a `user` first, and have an `after_create` filter, to create the `client` after the `user` has been created.

```
after_create :create_client
```

I have a new case where the `client` exists, and I want to create the `user` **after** the `client` already exists.  In this case, when I create the `user` I'd like to skip the `after_create` filter.

I understand that I'll need `after_create :create_client, unless: ____` but I'm not sure how to distinguish this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this case you can create a instance variable using attr_accessor

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :has_client
  ...
end
```

and you can assign boolean value to this variable and restrict after_create with `if condition`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  after_create :create_client, unless: :has_client
  ...
end
```

Comment: I literally just figured this out as I saw your response.  For some reason I thought `attr_accessor` was gone in Rails 4, but it's useful in this case

Comment: You're probably thinking of `attr_accessible`, which is indeed gone in Rails 4. `attr_accessor` is a straight-Ruby feature.

Comment: @CoreyWoodcox yes, i have heard the same but haven't found it on official Rails Doc. please share your findings.